# Change the "Leave Closed" and "Reopen" button's title in Reopen Votes Review Queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

The title which I meant is this:

[image: The titles]

The problem is, the **Leave Closed** button's title is:

> disagree with this reopen vote

And the Reopen button's title is:

> agree with this reopen vote

However, the explanation of why is this question inside Reopen Queue is:

> The question was *edited* after it was closed. Should it be reopened?

[image: The explanation]

And there's also no reopen votes on it.

---

So, if there's no reopen votes on it, disagree/agree what?

Comment: I think this would get more attention if you included a sample of what the titles should be instead; while it's obvious that they're not strictly *correct*, it's not obvious what their rather minor imprecision should be replaced with.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Well, I'm not a native English speaker. So I don't know replace it with what would be better. However if you have any ideas about it, feel free to edit my question :)